# WritingDirection works in react native ?

Tags: react-native

I want to know

```
 writingDirection:'rtl'
```

works in react native ? 
if not what is its alternative ? 
i want to write urdu or arabic for  
in my react native application

Comment: The React Native team has a blog post on RTL that you could try https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html

Comment: already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used `textAlign:'right'` for this